# Elastic search - handling the condition using must or must not query

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a requirement if newId is there then we have to get the data less than  todays date
and if newId field is not there in the data then we have to get the data till expiry date + 2Months.
I was trying below query but result has not come as expected.

```
 {
    "id":"234",
    "startDate":"23/07/2020",
    "endDate":"24/09/20202",
    "newId":"2345"
    },
   {
    "id":"234",
    "startDate":"23/07/2020",
    "endDate":"24/09/20202",
    "newId":null
    },
{
    "id":"235",
    "startDate":"23/07/2020",
    "endDate":"24/06/2020",
    "newId":"2345"
    },
```

> Query that I was trying

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
             
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "newId"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "endDate": {
                          "gte":"now/d"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                       {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "newId"
                      }
                    },
                   
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "endDate": {
                          "gte": "now-2M"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> Expected result

{
"id":"234",
"startDate":"23/07/2020",
"endDate":"24/09/20202",
"newId":"2345"
},
{
"id":"234",
"startDate":"23/07/2020",
"endDate":"24/09/20202",
"newId":null
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start! Your query is almost right, but you need a few more tweaks, namely to use `should` instead of `must`, because both sub-queries will never be true at the same time:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "newId"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "endDate": {
                    "gte": "now/d"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "endDate": {
                    "gte": "now-2M"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "newId"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It works. Thanks for your help. I have created new post. Could you help to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541023/elastic-search-query-which-should-cover-for-all-special-characters